# How to check change of contents in file from shell script

Tags: bash

I am new to shell scripting, I have requirement to check a date_trigger.txt file continuously for date change.

content of date_trigger.txt are as below :

```
trigger_date, value
17/03/2021, v1
```

The script (fetch_date.sh) should wait until date (17/03/2021) inside date_trigger.txt has not changed to current date. date_trigger.txt will be updated by another script with current date, hence the idea/need for fetch_date.sh script is to keep checking date_trigger.txt file and once it has found that date has been updated to current date then exit the code.

I have written a basic shell script for this as below, but so far no luck:

```
#! /bin/bash

sys_cur_date=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y")
while IFS=, read -r trigger_date value
  do
    while [ $sys_cur_date != $trigger_date ]; do
      echo " Where is my current date ?"
    done
      echo "I got my current date "
      break
  done < date_trigger.txt
```

Comment: Quotes matter. `while [ "$sys_cur_date" != "$trigger_date" ]` or dates with spaces won't work (will fail with a loud error message, or depending on what the contents are, could even falsely return true).

Comment: ...for example, consider if your `trigger_date` is `1 -o 1 = 1` -- that'll make it something like `[ 17/03/2021 != 1 -o 1 = 1 ]`; because "-o" is "or" and `1 = 1` is true, that's true even though it's a completely different date value; that bug goes away when you quote your expansions correctly.

Comment: BTW, the `sh` tag should be used for `#!/bin/sh` scripts, not `#!/bin/bash` scripts; they're two different languages (like C and C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, see below code. I think the -n1 in tail command was creating an issue, not sure if that was a typing error or that's an actual syntax.

```
#! /bin/bash
#fetch system current date
sys_cur_date=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y")

while IFS=, read -r trigger_date value < <(tail -1 date_trigger.txt)
  do
  if [[ $sys_cur_date == $trigger_date ]]; then
    echo "I got my current date"
    break
    #using break statement to control infinte loop here.
  else
    echo $trigger_date
    echo "Where is my current date ?"
  fi
done < date_trigger.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a sleep inside an infinite `while` loop, something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sys_cur_date=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y")

while :; do
  IFS=, read -r trigger_date value < <(tail -n1 date_trigger.txt)
  if [[ $sys_cur_date != "$trigger_date" ]]; then
    printf "Where is my current date %s\n" "$trigger_date"
  else
    printf "I got my current date %s\n" "$trigger_date"
    break
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Since you're only interested at the second line which contains the date, the `tail -n1` only prints the last line for `read` to process.

If you're not going to process `value` later, it can be replaced with an underscore `_`. It is like a dummy variable, just saying.

Comment: I executed this code, keeps printing where is my current date when date_trigger.txt doesn't have same date as system date. But does nothing if in between the execution I change contents of date_trigger.txt file from old date to current date.
Not sure if i have missed anything

Comment: It is basically the same as what your script is trying to do. If I understood it correctly.

Comment: Yes, Sleep did came in handy. But the problem that I am trying to solve is that script (fetch_date.sh) should wait until date (17/03/2021) inside date_trigger.txt has not changed to current date. date_trigger.txt will be updated by another script with current date, hence the idea/need for fetch_date.sh script is to keep checking date_trigger.txt file and once it has found that date has been updated to current date then exit the code.

Comment: Ok, you could try changing the test operator from `!=` to `==` and see where it gets you.

Comment: That just give me I got my current date as result, even on mismatch dates.

Comment: Right, the message is misleading right now, but does it say always the same message?